# Bolzano's Theorem for a vector function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^{2}$ continuous on [a,b], derivable on (a,b). Show that exists $c\in (a,b)$ such that $(f(b)-f(a))^{\bot}\cdot f'(c)=0$

Note: if $A=(a,b)$ then $A^{\bot}=(-b,a)$

It is supposed to be resolved with Bolzano's theorem.

**My try**

Let $f=(f_{1},f_{2})$, then

$(f(b)-f(a))^{\bot}=(f_{2}(a)-f_{2}(b),f_{1}(b)-f_{1}(a))$

and $f'(x)=(f_{1}'(x),f_{2}'(x))$

Let $g(x)=(f_{2}(a)-f_{2}(b))f_{1}'(x)+(f_{1}(b)-f_{1}(a))f_{2}'(x)$

Because of the mean value theorem this can be written as

$g(x)=(b-a)(f_{1}'(c_{1})f_{2}'(x)-f_{2}'(c_{2})f_{1}'(x))$, with $c_{1}$ and $c_{2}\in (a,b)$

So I think I must show that $g(c_{1})$ and $g(c_{2})$ are opposite sign and then apply Bolzano's theorem but I can't see why they are opposite sign since:

$g(c_{1})=(b-a)(f_{1}'(c_{1})f_{2}'(c_{1})-f_{2}'(c_{2})f_{1}'(c_{1}))$

and

$g(c_{2})=(b-a)(f_{1}'(c_{1})f_{2}'(c_{2})-f_{2}'(c_{2})f_{1}'(c_{2}))$

Comment: "Show that there exists $c\in (a,b)$ such that $(f(b)-f(a))^{\bot}\cdot f'(c)$" seems to be incomplete. What property should $(f(b)-f(a))^{\bot}\cdot f'(c)$ have?

Comment: that is equal to 0, sorry I forgot to write that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g(x)=\langle (f(b)-f(a))^{\perp},f(x)-f(a)\rangle$ $g(a)=g(b)=0$, this implies (Rolle) that there exists $c\in (a,b)$ with $g'(c)=\langle (f(a)-f(b))^{\perp},f'(c)\rangle=0$.